# Нужно вывести из списка количество чисел кратных 3. Не понимаю, в чём ошибка. Python

Tags: python

```
a = str(input('Введите числа: ')).split()
print(len(list(filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0, a))))
```

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Почему вылазит такая ошибка? Вроде все правильно. Str перед input ни на что не влияет. И важно, делать не через цикл, а через максимально короткий код, что бы было как можно меньше строк

Comment: str перед input ни на что не влияет. потому что input и так возвращает str. а вам нужно получить список чисел. то есть все элементы списка сначала перевести в числа, а потом уже фильтровать.

Comment: Ну и как это сделать?

Comment: Вы как оах получаете в `a` массив строк. И пытаетесь для каждого-элемента строки найти остаток. Сначала вам нужно преобразовать всё в числа через краткий итератор (списковое включение) или `map`

Comment: *Чтобы было как можно меньше строк* - `print(len([i for i in a if int(i)%3==0]))
`

Answer (score 0):

после split вы получаете список, в котором каждый элемент строка. Следует применить функцию map

```
len(list(filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0,map(int, a))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете прямо внутри `lambda` преобразовать в `int`. Ну и в целом можно короче записать, без лишних преобразований, пользуясь тем, что при арифметических действиях `True` считается как `1`, а `False` как `0`:

```py
a = input('Введите числа: ').split()
print(sum(map(lambda x: int(x) % 3 == 0, a)))
```

Answer (score -2):

Не надо спешить и затруднять себе жизнь.
Медленно, шаг за шагом:

```
list_of_strings = input('Введите числа: ').split()            # список чисел в форме строк
iter_of_ints    = map(int, list_of_strings)                   # конверсия в итератор чисел
iter_of_3_mult  = filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0, iter_of_ints)  # выбираем только кратные 3

for element in iter_of_3_mult:
    print(element)
```

---

Разве ли это не более красивое, чем например вторую и третью строку этого кода объединить в одну, заменяя в 3-й строке `iter_of_ints` его определением в 2-й строке?

```
iter_of_3_mult  = filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0, map(int, list_of_strings))
```

Или затем даже выводить это, сначала конвертируя в список?

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: x % 3 == 0, map(int, list_of_strings))))
```

По моему страшное сделать все в одной строке программы, я лично не вижу в том никакой красоты.